# Como filtrar dados do realtime database do firebase

Tags: firebase, next.js

Eu tenho uma lista de produtos que possuem categoria, e quero filtra-los por categoria.
Meu projeto esta sendo desenvolvido em Next.js.
Não estou conseguindo filtrar os dados usando os metódos do Firebase, quero usa-los para evitar fazer código eu mesmo, e ter que rodar a função de filtrar toda vez que o usuario escolher uma categoria, já que a categoria vem atraves da URI, e eu pego o param.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const category = ctx.query.category;

  const reference = ref(getDatabase());
  const listaDeProdutos = [];

  const products = await get(child(reference, 'products')).then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    return snapshot.val();
  });

  for (let key in products) {
    listaDeProdutos.push({
      ...products[key],
      id: key,
    });
  }

  return {
    props: { products: listaDeProdutos, category: category },
  };
}
```

Este é meu código normal

Então, eu já tentei isso: `orderByChild()`e `equalTo()`, de acordo com essa documentação:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data

Eu tenho algo assim:

```
  const products = await get(reference, orderByChild('categorias'), equalTo('livros')).then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    return snapshot.val();
  })
```

Mas isso também não funcionou.

A saída esperada que eu quero são apenas os produtos que possuem a "categoria" child com o valor "books"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após bastante estudo consegui resolver esse problema.

O metódo `get` recebe um objeto `Query` como argumento.
Então para dar certo, eu criei a query antes e depois passei ela para o `get` e assim eu peguei o snapshot( retorno do metódo get ) e ele veio filtrado.

```
category !== 'all'
    ? (productsQ = query(ref(database, 'products'), orderByChild('categoria'), equalTo(category)))
    : (productsQ = query(ref(database, 'products')));

  const products = await get(productsQ).then(snapshot => {
    return snapshot.val();
  });
```

Se estiver usando next.js como eu, importante usar o `await` no get, caso contrário o retorno será null.